# Erro de NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at DAO.Database.verificaSeTemRegistroNaTabela(Database.java:184)

Esse erro foi apresentado no meu `logcat`.

**O método:**

```
public boolean verificaSeTemRegistroNaTabela(String tabela){
    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM '" + tabela + "'";
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sqlSelect, null);
    if (res.getCount() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Linha com erro:**

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery(sqlSelect, null);
```

Comment: Verifica se não é o **db** que ta nulo, como vc está chamando esse método *verificaSeTemRegistroNaTabela*?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `db`. Tem certeza que ele não tá nulo?

Comment: Leia isso: [injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Comment: retire as aspas simples `String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM " + tabela;` e verifique a variável `db`

Answer (score 1):

Como citado nos comentários pelo Virgilio, seu erro está em passar a tabela com aspas simples.

Pegue o valor da variavel `sqlSelect` e rode no seu banco de dados, ocorrerá o erro.

Faça a passagem de parâmetros para comandos sql sempre passando por bind variables, tornará seu código mais seguro e simples de dar manutenção futuramente.